# API. Как получить ограниченный список значений из таблицы PostgreSQL? (JAVA)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Есть таблица t_user, в которой хранятся пользователи.
Мне нужно вытащить список всех пользователей, но так как в таблице 200к значений то хочу ограничивать список на фронте по 50-100-150-200 пользователей и т.д.

Помогите плз с написанием API

Comment: Добавьте к запросу LIMIT 100.

Comment: Возможно вы не правильно поняли)
Мне не нужен sql запрос, мне нужно на Java получить список юзеров

Comment: Всех пользователей можете вытащить? Если да, то покажите код чтобы было понятнее на каком уровне вносить ограничение. Если нет, то вопрос слишком общий: нужно уточнить с чем именно сложности.

Answer (score 4):

Ограничить выборку в Hibernate/JPA поможет метод [setMaxResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setMaxResults-int-) интерфейса Query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User");
query.setMaxResults(50);
List<User> userList = query.list();
```

Если же вы работаете с JPA Data, то вместо CrudRepository, используйте [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html):

```
PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> repository = …
Page<User> users = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 50));
List<User> userList = users.getContent();
```

Comment: работает, спасибо!
а не подскажите как лучше сделать подсчет?
Чтобы код подсчитал что выбрано 50 юзеров и выдавал на выходе цифру

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) У интерфейса `List` есть метод `size` возвращающий количество элементов.